# Combine multiple columns into one column in R by ID

Tags: r, group-by, associations

The dataset is as follows:

[image]

The output should be as follows

[image]

I have tried the following things

1. `sum <- gather(Learning_platform, A,B)`
   I used the `gather` function from `tidyr`, but it did not give me the desired result. It just gathered the data and separated it by underscores.

2.`df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(B = sum(B))`
This also did not work as the sum of factors could not be processed by R.

3. I also used the following example from the `tidyr` package to no avail:

`df %>% group_by(A,B) %>% 
       summarise(A,B)) %>% 
       spread(ID, A,B,C,D) %>% 
       ungroup() %>%`

Kindly suggest a solution or learning material for the above example.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gather`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, - ID) %>%
    filter(val != "") %>%
    select(-key) %>%
    arrange(ID)
```

---

If the blank is `NA`, then we can remove those elements within the `gather` itself

```
gather(df1, key, val, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    select(-key) %>%
    arrange(ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `reshape2`.

```
reshape(df, idvar = "ID", varying = list(2:5), direction = "long") %>%
  arrange(ID) %>% select(-time)
```